# Check Constraint For A Defaulting Value

Tags: oracle

I'm stuck and can't figure out how to add the condition to the CHECK constraint in oracle...
Basically I have a table with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TBL
(
    COL_1 VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
    COL_2 VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
    COL_3 VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
    COL_4 VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
    DEF_COL CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'Y',
    CONSTRAINT def_check_const
    CHECK (???????)
);
```

There may be multiple values in this table, however I require that only 'Y' or 'N' can be entered in the DEF_COL column. Also i want to add a constraint to restrict the number of 'Y' in the DEF_COL column to only one. There may be multiple 'N' entries allowed for DEF_COL column. Please could someone guide me as to what must be done to add the constraint in the check section of the create table query?

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TBL(
    COL_1 VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
    COL_2 VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
    COL_3 VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
    COL_4 VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
    DEF_COL CHAR(1)     DEFAULT 'Y'
                        CONSTRAINT def_check_const
                          CHECK ( DEF_COL IN ('Y', 'N' ) )
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX def_col_only_one_y__U
  ON TEST_TBL( CASE DEF_COL WHEN 'Y' THEN 'Y' END );
```

**Insert a row**:

```
INSERT INTO TEST_TBL VALUES ( 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'Y' );

1 rows inserted.
```

**Insert a second column with `DEF_COL = 'Y'`**:

```
INSERT INTO TEST_TBL VALUES ( 'B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'Y' )

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00001: unique constraint (TEST.DEF_COL_ONLY_ONE_Y__U) violated
00001. 00000 -  "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated"
*Cause:    An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.
           For Trusted Oracle configured in DBMS MAC mode, you may see
           this message if a duplicate entry exists at a different level.
*Action:   Either remove the unique restriction or do not insert the key.
```

**Update**:

To have only one `Y` for each unique combination of 3 columns then try:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX C1_2_3__def_col_only_one_y__U
      ON TEST_TBL( COL1, COL2, COL3, CASE DEF_COL WHEN 'Y' THEN 'Y' END );
```

Comment: Hello @MT0, is it also possible to have multiple 'Y' entries based on the values of the col_1, col_2 and col_3. All these three columns would contain unique values.